# Looking for a more efficient way to break IP addresses into octets

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that stores an IP address masks, for validating if users are allowed to access a resource based on their IP Address.  For me to validate against their IP Address, I break their address, and the masks, into octets and compare them.  I have a way that works, but it isn't sitting well with me, as it seems overly heavy on string manipulation, which is slow in T-SQL.  This strikes me as being a 'Brute Force' method, and not at all elegant.  I'm hoping someone can offer some improvements, while keeping to the same output.

Some sample masks are as follows:

- *.*.*.* - This is the most common, which is "for all possible IP
  addresses"
- 172.16.*.*  - This specifies IP addresses that start with 172.16
- 172.16.0-10.* - This specifies IP addresses that start with 172.16, but where the third octet is between 0 and 10
- 172.16.99.10 - This specifies an individual address.

To parse these out, I declare a temp table:

```
DECLARE @Rights TABLE(
IPAddr char(15)
, octet1 char(7)
, octet1max char(3)
, octet2 char(7)
, octet2max char(3)
, octet3 char(7)
, octet3max char(3)
, octet4 char(7)
, octet4max char(3)
, dot int
, tlen int
, tempaddr char(15)
)
```

I start by inserting the records from my database table into my temp table:

```
INSERT @Rights(IPAddress, dot, tlen, tempaddr)
SELECT IPAddress, CHARINDEX('.',IPAddress), LEN(IPAddress), IPAddress
FROM IPAccessRights_Info
```

Then, I run 4 `UPDATE` statements against this temp table:

```
UPDATE @Rights
SET octet1 = SUBSTRING(tempaddr, 0, dot)
    , tempaddr = SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot)
    , dot = CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot))
    , tlen = LEN(SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot))
UPDATE @Rights
SET octet2 = SUBSTRING(tempaddr, 0, dot)
    , tempaddr = SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot)
    , dot = CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot))
    , tlen = LEN(SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot))
UPDATE @Rights
SET octet3 = SUBSTRING(tempaddr, 0, dot)
    , octet4 = SUBSTRING(tempaddr, dot+1, LEN(tempaddr)-dot)
    , dot = NULL
    , tlen = LEN(IPAddr)
    , tempaddr = NULL

-- Parse out any ranges
UPDATE @Rights
    SET octet1 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet1, 0, CHARINDEX('-', octet1)) ELSE octet1 END
        , octet1max = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet1, CHARINDEX('-', octet1)+1, LEN(octet1)) ELSE NULL END
        , octet2 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet2) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet2, 0, CHARINDEX('-', octet2)) ELSE octet2 END
        , octet2max = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet2) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet2, CHARINDEX('-', octet2)+1, LEN(octet2)) ELSE NULL END
        , octet3 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet3) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet3, 0, CHARINDEX('-', octet3)) ELSE octet3 END
        , octet3max = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet3) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet3, CHARINDEX('-', octet3)+1, LEN(octet3)) ELSE NULL END
        , octet4 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet4) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet4, 0, CHARINDEX('-', octet4)) ELSE octet4 END
        , octet4max = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', octet4) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(octet4, CHARINDEX('-', octet4)+1, LEN(octet4)) ELSE NULL END
```

When I'm done, I can then use the values in octet1-octet4 and octet1max-octet4max to match up against my IP address.

Of course, when we all go IPv6, then this will be a whole different can of worms...

Comment: If your existing code works, this might be a better question for [codereview.se]...

Comment: This looks like an ideal task for an SQL CLR procedure and the [IPAddress Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.IPAddress%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: You can always avoid chars and use only INT, when is * you can leave it null and do the math.

Comment: Check out the **PARSENAME** function in T-SQL - ideal for not only parsing 4-part names, but any of 4 items separated by periods, such as IP addresses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx

Comment: SLICK!  `PARSENAME` looks like it is my immediate elegant winner!  I still have to deal with handling any ranges (i.e. '10-20') but this really cleans up the code, and leaves it looking much tidier.  All I need to do is add a comment to help (me) to remember what `PARSENAME` is and why I'd be using it in such an odd way, but that's easily done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Tip-of-the-day](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=a87aff52-234f-4e3a-bb52-1d83d3635375&tkw=uses-of-the-parsename-function) ([and this one](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data)) describes how to use the [T-SQL PARSENAME function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)
to separate IP addresses as well as 4-part database object names.

```
DECLARE @IPAddresses TABLE ( [IPAddress] VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @IPAddresses VALUES ('10.0.0.1')
INSERT INTO @IPAddresses VALUES ('255.255.255.255')
INSERT INTO @IPAddresses VALUES ('192.123.545.12')
INSERT INTO @IPAddresses VALUES ('1.2.3.4')

SELECT * FROM @IPAddresses
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME([IPAddress], 4) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME([IPAddress], 3) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME([IPAddress], 2) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME([IPAddress], 1) AS INT)

IPAddress
----------------
1.2.3.4
10.0.0.1
192.123.545.12
255.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm completely off here, but I can imagine that your orignal table isn't fit for the usage.

If would define the table `IPAccessRights_Info` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IPAccessRights_Info](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IpAddress] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Octet1Min] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet1Max] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet2Min] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet2Max] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet3Min] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet3Max] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet4Min] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Octet4Max] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IPAccessRights_Info] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And when you insert the IpAddress Rights from your management application (I making the assumption you have some kind of management layer for this) you do the nasty job of splitting the values of the IpAddress in octets, the task to query against this is far easier.

And I think you only need a OctetMin and OctetMax column. Translated from your examples:

```
*.*.*.* => Octet1Min = 0, Octet1Max = 255, Octet2Min = 0, etc.
172.16.*.* => Octet1Min = 172, Octet1Max = 172, etc.
172.16.0-10.* => Octet3Min = 0, Octet3Max = 10, etc.
172.16.99.10 => Octet4Min = 10, Octet4Max = 10, etc.
```

You can query against this, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.IPAccessRights_Info VALUES (4,'172.16.9-10.*',172,172,16,16,9,10,0,255)

-- IpAddress to check
DECLARE @IpAddress nvarchar(15) = '172.16.10.5'

DECLARE @octet1 nvarchar(3) = SUBSTRING(@IpAddress, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @IpAddress)) 
SET @IpAddress = RIGHT(@IpAddress, LEN(@IpAddress)-LEN(@octet1) - 1)
DECLARE @octet2 nvarchar(3) = SUBSTRING(@IpAddress, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @IpAddress)) 
SET @IpAddress = RIGHT(@IpAddress, LEN(@IpAddress)-LEN(@octet2) - 1)
DECLARE @octet3 nvarchar(3) = SUBSTRING(@IpAddress, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @IpAddress)) 
SET @IpAddress = RIGHT(@IpAddress, LEN(@IpAddress)-LEN(@octet3) - 1)
DECLARE @octet4 nvarchar(3) = @IpAddress

SELECT  Id
FROM    dbo.IPAccessRights_Info
WHERE   Octet1Min <= CAST(@octet1 AS int)
AND     Octet1Max >= CAST(@octet1 AS int)
AND     Octet2Min <= CAST(@octet2 AS int)
AND     Octet2Max >= CAST(@octet2 AS int)
AND     Octet3Min <= CAST(@octet3 AS int)
AND     Octet3Max >= CAST(@octet3 AS int)
AND     Octet4Min <= CAST(@octet4 AS int)
AND     Octet4Max >= CAST(@octet4 AS int)

-- Results:
    1
    2
    4
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, for sure, but the underlying table structure isn't something they are ready to optimize quite yet.  The task I'm taking on is that of extracting some business logic out of a brittle application and putting into a SQL stored procedure.

Comment: I'm completely unaware the application you're working on, so the choices maybe limited. Nevertheless, before you continue and you go the way of adding stored procedures to the system instead of taking them out, read this: [Stored Procedures are EVIL](http://www.tonymarston.co.uk/php-mysql/stored-procedures-are-evil.html)

Comment: True, I kept many of the details out in the interests of focusing on the core problem, that of parsing the IP address.  For me, I separate Triggers from Stored Procedures.  I have learned to hate triggers, because they are mostly invisible when debugging.  Stored procedures, however, have their place.  In this case, the in-app code was hitting the database 4 times, whereas the SP will do it much more efficiently.  Also, this SProc will be called once on app start-up, so its effect on the system is minimal either way.